# Jquery dialog is not loading latest dynamic content after second insert

Tags: jquery, ajax

On click image, it should pop up a dialog with all the content coming from database.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#click-for-modal').click(function() {
            $("#my-modal-div").load('history.html');
            $('#my-modal-div').dialog({modal: true});
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I am calling script as

```
<img id="click-for-modal" th:src="@{/images/history.png}" th:width="30" th:height="30" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
<div id="my-modal-div" title="History"></div>
```

This code when called second time after some inserted data, it is not reloading the history.html page.

Please suggest.

I have tried ajax as well:

```
<div id="my-modal-div" title="History">
<a href="/DocWorks/history.html"
onclick="jQuery('#my-modal-div').dialog('open'); return false">
<img id="click-for-modal" th:src="@{/images/history.png}"
th:width="30" th:height="30" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
</a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "history.html",
            success: function(){
                $("#my-modal-div").html(data);
            }   
        });
```

Here, the history data is reloaded with the changes but it is directing it to another page as i have given `<a href="/DocWorks/history.html"`

Please suggest any 1 of the above method to fix the issue

Comment: try this call dialog inside callback method of load function $("#my-modal-div").load('history.html',function(){ display modal here  });

Comment: I didnt get what is "display modal here". I have tried this:  $('#click-for-modal').click(function() {
   $("#my-modal-div").load('history.html', function(){model : true});
   $('#my-modal-div').dialog();
  });
this didnt work as well.

Comment: please write this code $('#my-modal-div').dialog({modal: true}); in  function callback. why are you write only model:true in that callback ? please update your  question with current code.

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#click-for-modal').click(function() {
   $("#my-modal-div").load('history.html', function() {
    $('#my-modal-div').dialog();
   });
  });
 });


<img id="click-for-modal" th:src="@{/images/history.png}"
    th:width="30" th:height="30" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
   <div id="my-modal-div" title="History"></div>